# change <br /> to \n\r in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done text replacement in Javascript such that the `<br />` tag will be replaced by the `\n\r` .  This seems to work in IE8.0 but not in chrome and firefox.  why is that so? How can I make it work in chrome and firefox. Why does chrome and firefox not consider `<br/>` tags as `<br/>` but rather `<br>`?

Comment: What do you need this for? Can you elaborate on your situation? There may be a better/easier way for what you want to do.

Comment: In the future, you really need to show the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working fine everywhere:

```
"Hello<br />World".replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\r\n");
```

Comment: Sometimes simple mistake happens like : Some one can use "</br>" , in this case use replace(/<\s*\/?br>/ig, "\r\n")

Comment: 1 this the best solution