# How to replace an HTML <br> with newline character "\n"?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I replace HTML `<BR> <BR/> or <BR />` with new line character "\n"

Comment: He's doing the inverse of that, @GolezTrol

Comment: `"Your<br>String".replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\r\n")`

Comment: @Polynomial Yeah, you're right. Still the answer is to be found a dozen of times on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672460/change-br-to-n-r-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: Indeed. He should've searched before posting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+br+%5Cn

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery javascript regex Replace <br> with \n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959415/jquery-javascript-regex-replace-br-with-n) (includes answers that do not involve jQuery)

Comment: Sometimes simple mistake happens like : Some one can use "</br>" , in this case use replace(/<\s*\/?br>/ig, "\r\n")

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're looking for an equivilent of PHP's `nl2br()`. This should do the job:

```
function br2nl(str) {
    return str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have a function called `br2nl`.

Comment: Haha, oops. Good catch. I meant the inverse of `nl2br()`. Though it really *should* have that function :(

Comment: Sometimes simple mistake happens like : Some one can use "</br>" , in this case use replace(/<\s*\/?br>/ig, "\r\n")

Answer (score 1):

A cheap function:

```
function brToNewLine(str) {
    return str.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, "\n");
}
```

es.

```
vat str = "Hello<br \>world!";
var result = brToNewLine(str);
```

The result is: "Hello/nworld!"

Answer (score 1):

This function considers whether to remove or replace the tags such as `<br>`, `<BR>`, `<br />`, `</br>`.

```
/**
 * This function inverses text from PHP's nl2br() with default parameters.
 *
 * @param {string} str Input text
 * @param {boolean} replaceMode Use replace instead of insert
 * @return {string} Filtered text
 */
function br2nl (str, replaceMode) {   

  var replaceStr = (replaceMode) ? "\n" : '';
  // Includes <br>, <BR>, <br />, </br>
  return str.replace(/<\s*\/?br\s*[\/]?>/gi, replaceStr);
}
```

In your case, you need to use `replaceMode`. For eaxmple: `br2nl('1st<br>2st', true)`

[Demo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgrw3hj1/7/)

> [JavaScript nl2br & br2nl functions](https://gist.github.com/yidas/41cc9272d3dff50f3c9560fb05e7255e)