# jquery :Find the new line character and replace it with <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page one of the table column has the html like below

```
My world Logistics,\n Hamburg Industriestrasse \n 21107 Megas Sorter HH India
```

wherever there is \n i need to replace it withe html tag `<br>`

How can do it in Jquery, javascript?

Comment: This is pretty trivial. Did you try the `replace()` method?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How replace HTML <br> with newline character "\n"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062399/how-replace-html-br-with-newline-character-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
var messagetoSend = document.getElementById('x').value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
alert(messagetoSend);
</script>
```

X is the table name.

Comment: `var messagetoSend = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");`