# Why is replace('<br>/g', '\n') not working

Tags: javascript

```
"test<br>test<br>test<br>test".replace('/<br>/g', '\n');
```

Does not replace the `<br>`'s with `\n`, it leaves the string unchanged. I can't figure out why.

Comment: `'/<br>/g'` is a string, not a regex.  Lose the quotes.  It's looking for the *literal* string `'/<br>/g'`.  You want `.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');`.  JavaScript has RegEx literals.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062399/how-replace-html-br-with-newline-character-n

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you're passing the regex object as a string instead of a regex. Remove the `''` from the first argument you're passing to `replace()`

Answer (score 12):

You need to use a Regex literal, not a string:

```
"test<br>test<br>test<br>test".replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
```