# Replace <br /> in a textarea with a line separator ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline, cakephp-2.1

I guess this will be answered in two minutes but I am not able to google out a solution.

Tried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062399/how-replace-html-br-with-newline-character-n), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672460/change-br-to-n-r-in-firefox-and-chrome)

I have a textarea which first recieves some data from the server (dynamically using AJAX). The text in the textarea may look like this:

```
Hello&nbsp;Cruel&nbsp;<br&nbsp;/>World!
```

My users do not like the look of this :)

So I wrote a very simple function:

```
    function replaceHtml( string_to_replace ) 
    {
        var result = replaceAll( string_to_replace, "&nbsp;", " ");
        result = result.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n\r"); // or "\n", "\r", "\r\n"
        return result;
     }
```

My output looks like this:

```
Hello Cruel World!
```

Instead of:

```
Hello Cruel
World!
```

I would love a solution that is at most 5 lines long and can be applied with all browsers and OSes

Btw, Im no fan of regexes, so maybe the real problem will be there..

**UPDATE**

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833269/javascript-platform-independent-line-separator) and mr Michael_B I got this solution, which is working for me, but I've got a hunch the character might not be the best solution there is:

```
function replaceHtml( string_to_replace ) 
{
    return string_to_replace.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '\u2028');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try '\n\r' instead of "\n\r" (simple quote replace double quotes)

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfffg/

Comment: @joDev Single quotes and double quotes are equivalent in Javascript

Comment: replaceAll isn't a function

Comment: @Explosion Pills: can't believe it, but its not working for me..

`function replaceHtml( string_to_replace ) 
  {
   var result = string_to_replace.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '\n');
   return result;
  }`

Comment: Jeff Shaver: written my own, which seems to be working ( as u can see in my output)

Comment: I've added a potential fix to your `\u2028` problem...give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Explosion Pills comment and jsFiddle

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfffg/1/)**

```
function replaceHtml( string_to_replace ) 
{
        return string_to_replace.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '\n');
}
```

**UPDATE** based on [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfffg/3/)**

Maybe this will fix your issue with `\n` - Requires jQuery.

```
function replaceHtml(string_to_replace) {
    return $("<div>").append(string_to_replace.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '&#13;&#10;')).text();
}
```

Comment: I'm using Mozilla 19.0 and it's working fine for me.  Are you looking at it on jsFiddle or in your own solution?

Comment: On jsFiddle it works, not on my solution..

I just tried to replace the '\n' part with this: '\u2028' from
[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833269/javascript-platform-independent-line-separator) and it works on my solution, but I've got a hunch that's not the best way to do this..

Still I'll give you a +1 for a nice code, but till I figure out what's going on in the textarea, I don't know if it's ok to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Could you provide some more of your code...are you typing this info into the text area? What's calling `replaceHtml`?  Can you recreate the problem you are having with `\n` in jsfiddle?

Comment: If I change my solution to `\u2028` it does not work on Chrome or Firefox on my machine.

Comment: There is a lot of code going on and I dont think I could recreate the problem in jsFiddle.

I could write down the logic that's going on, and some source codes of what's happening, but it would be a lot of code and I do not think it will help you solve my problem..  By the way, the #13#10 thing didnt work on chrome as well..

Comment: I understand. But if I can't recreate the problem, I can't really debug. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but should it not be `$.replaceAll()` as it's a jQuery function not JS?

Or `replace()` in pure Javascript?

Comment: Honestly: did not know there was a $.replaceAll() :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to use jQuery in there:

```
function replaceHtml( string_to_replace ) 
{
    var result = string_to_replace.replace(/\&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n\r"); // or "\n", "\r", "\r\n"
    return result;
 }
```